# Are the perfect-free sets countable?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Let $A$ be subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that contains no nonempty perfect subsets. Is $A$  countable?

Answer (score 6):

No. If $\aleph_1<2^{\aleph_0}$ then uncountable set of cardinality smaller than $2^{\aleph_0}$ does not contain a perfect subset. But more generally we can construct something called a Bernstein set which has size $2^{\aleph_0}$ but does not contain a perfect subset.

The construction is by transfinite induction and it uses a well-ordering of $2^{\aleph_0}$. And indeed it is consistent that the axiom of choice fails, and every uncountable set of real numbers contains a perfect subset.

---

**Related questions:**

- [A set which is neither meagre nor comeagre in any interval.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119021/a-set-which-is-neither-meagre-nor-comeagre-in-any-interval)

Answer (score 2):

On the other hand, assuming the Axiom of Determinacy (which contradicts the axiom of choice) every subset of a Polish space has the Perfect Set Property, namely it is either countable or it contains a Cantor set.

Comment: The perfect set property is **much** weaker than the axiom of determinacy. All it implies is that $\omega_1$ is a limit cardinal in $L$. It is in fact the accurate provability bound, since if we repeat the Solovay model construction using any limit cardinal we get a model where the perfect set property holds; however that model will satisfy $\sf DC$ if and only if $\omega_1$ is regular if and only if we began from an inaccessible cardinal. In either case the resulting model will not satisfy $\sf AD$.

Comment: Thanks for this very precise piece of information. I just wanted to point out that the answer to the question is consistently "yes" in ZF.

Comment: The point is that in terms of consistency determinacy is so much more stronger than $\sf ZF$; but having the perfect set property isn't.

Comment: very interesting, i did not know, thanks.

Comment: No problem. It's not a commonly known fact. Specker proved that if $M$ is a model of $\sf ZF$ in which the perfect set property holds, then $\omega_1^M$ is a limit cardinal in $L$. Truss work (which was to repeat the Solovay model construction from an arbitrary limit cardinal) shows that indeed taking any limit cardinal yields that result; but if we do not start with an inaccessible cardinal (an assumption whose strength exceeds that of $\sf ZF$) then in the resulting model $\omega_1$ is going to be a countable union of countable sets.